# A strange convergence for a semigroup of operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, semigroups-of-operators, functional-calculus

I am reading B. Simon's ["Kato's inequality and the comparison of semigroups"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002212367990079X/pdf), and I am having troubles understanding a part of the proof of Theorem 1 therein, that goes as follows:

*Let $A,B$ be semibounded self-adjoint operators on some $L^2(M, \mu)$, such that $\mathrm e ^{-t A} f \ge 0$ for all $f \ge 0$. Denote by $D(A)$ the domain of $A$, and by $Q(A)$ the domain of the quadratic form associated to $A$. If $| \mathrm e ^{-t B} u | \le \mathrm e ^{-t A} |u|$ for all $u$, then $u \in D(B)$ implies $|u| \in Q(A)$.*

The proof should be elementary and straightforward, but I am having difficulties with a certain passing to the limit. Specifically, if $u \in D(B)$, then it is clear from the general theory of $1$-parameter semigroups that

$$\lim _{t \to 0} \ \left( u, \frac {1 - \mathrm e ^{-t B}} t u \right) = (u, Bu) \ .$$

(Parantheses denote scalar product.)

> What is not clear to me, though, is why
>
> $$\lim _{t \to 0} \ \left( |u|, \frac {1 - \mathrm e ^{-t A}} t |u| \right) = (|u|, A |u|) \ .$$
>
> More specifically, why does the limit even exist? And why does $|u| \in D(A)$, in order to be able to write $A |u|$? Or am I misreading Simon's ideas?

Comment: Simon has the unfortunate habit of sometimes writing something like $(u,A u)$, when he means $q_A(u,u)$, where $q_A$ is the quadratic form associated with $A$. In any case, Ouhabaz' article "Invariance of Closed Convex Sets and Domination Criteria for Semigroups" seems to be the better source for domination of semigroups - for example, he gives characterization purely in terms of the quadratic forms where Simon has form and operator domains.

Comment: Simon refers to this explicitly in "[An abstract Kato inequality...](http://sloan2.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/76.pdf)", on page 1068 just after the Definition.